# Simulate sessions in CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, couchdb, sproutcore

I let CouchDB serve my Sproutcore application so there is no backend.

When the user logs in I want him to be remembered so he doesn't have to log in again.

With regular backend servers I used sessions for this.

Is there a way to simulate sessions in CouchDB?

If not, how do I make the application to remember him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use cookies, basic HTTP auth and OAuth to validate (and other 3rd party methods) to keep users in a session. There is also an API call to retrieve the current session user. (`_session`) Refer to [this page](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview) in the Wiki.

Comment: FrontPage > Reference > Security Features Overview